# 'Heavy Traffic' or 'Lot of Traffic'?

Tags: word-choice, writing

Is it appropriate to say 'Heavy Traffic'? I am referring to traffic as in roads and vehicles in this context.

Is using 'lot of traffic' more appropriate?

Comment: Elton John has a song titled "Heavy Traffic". He does not, however, have a song titled "Lot of Traffic". That should totally close the case once and for all. (^_^)

Comment: There is an American movie named 'Heavy Traffic' too :) 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Traffic

Comment: @RegDwight: Your profile disclaimer aside, I am not surprised someone with your screen name would have an exhaustive knowledge of Elton John's catalog. :)

Comment: @Robusto: indeed, there have been countless occasions on which I could have quoted Sir Elton, but this is the very first time I have actually done so, and only after previously quoting Zager & Evans, Sting, Simon & Garfunkel, and a children's song. I do try to be diverse.

Comment: @RegDwight: Zager & Evans, b'god! I didn't expect to hear a reference to that group for another 515 years!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think "Heavy Traffic" is quite commonly used and is totally appropriate

EDIT : On 2nd thoughts, i think they are both inter-changeble but it might depend on the formulation of the sentence - where one might suit better (depending on the overall style) as compared to the other.

Example:

> I was delayed for my meeting due to heavy traffic on the M1

Comment: ' There is lot of traffic on the M1 ' or ' There is heavy traffic on the M1 ' ?

Comment: Either. Both sound fine to me at least.

Comment: @Sairam: It needs to be "**a** lot of traffic", not "lot of traffic".

Comment: @Brian - I will keep that in mind as I am unable to edit my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Both "heavy traffic" and "a lot of traffic" are commonly used in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

As a traffic engineer, we use "heavy traffic" and "increased traffic volumes"